# Heroku Database setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am facing the below issue with `heroku run rake db:create`

Application in RubyonRails technology and Postgresql database.

```
This is the legacy Heroku CLI. Please install the new CLI from https://cli.heroku.com
Running rake db:create on ⬢ project-name... up, run.2367 (Free)
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "database"=>"abcdabcd", "username"=>"abcdabcd", "password"=>"abcdabcd", "port"=>5432, "host"=>"ec2-107-21-233-71.compute-1.amazonaws.com"}
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Can you tell me what I am missing to config in this app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run `db:create` on heroku. Instead, you need to provision a [postgresql add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql).
Doing so will create a database for you and give you it's credentials as the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

You can then run `db:migrate` to setup all the tables.
See also https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql